# PrimeNG - what are my options for adding a placeholder for a time picker?

Tags: javascript, angular, placeholder, timepicker

I am using the prime ng time picker

Is there any way (or work around) where I can have a text placeholder instead of a vacant time picker? (00:00)

```
<p-calendar #timePicker [timeOnly]="true" hourFormat="24> </p-calendar>
```

Or are there any time pickers that do allow text placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar) you can add `placeholder` property:

```
<p-calendar #timePicker [timeOnly]="true" hourFormat="24" placeholder="'enter your placeholder here'"> </p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bind a value of type Date in the p-calendar tag. This would display the date and time accordingly.

eg:

.html

```
<p-calendar #timePicker [timeOnly]="true" hourFormat="24" [(ngModel)]="currentDate"> </p-calendar>
```

.ts

```
currentDate: Date;
```

Comment: Hey, I am looking to add a text placeholder, not a date

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<p-calendar inputId="calendar"
              [showIcon]="true"  formControlName="startDate"
           class="form-control" date-format=" M/d/yy" [showTime]="true"  
             ></p-calendar>
```